# Accessing Youtube Recommendations

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to access Youtube APIs and get the recommendations for the user. I have tested it here https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities/list . I have also enabled Youtube Analytics API and Youtube Data API v3. I still keep getting this error. 
"Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
What am I doing wrong?

## Edit

Some additional logs

http://grab.by/uTk4

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by just creating a new Project. Not sure what went wrong with the old one.